# Using a string builder, i've read a file.. How do i find if the given string is present in the file or not?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

I've read a file into StringBuilder. 
When I give a string as an input, if the word is present in the file, the output should be true.. If its not present, it should be false.. How do i do it? Could someone help me with the code? I've written the program till here.. How do i go further? Thanks alot.. :)

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (StreamReader Reader = new StreamReader("C://myfile2.txt"))
        {
            StringBuilder Sb = new StringBuilder();
            Sb.Append(Reader.ReadToEnd());
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The File is read");   
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: sb.ToString().IndexOf("your_word"); [IndexOf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.indexof.aspx)

Comment: In this case, probably not! As a side note, everyone here suggest to use string.Contains, but internally string.Contains use string.IndexOf.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
using (System.IO.StreamReader Reader = new System.IO.StreamReader("C://myfile2.txt"))
{
      string fileContent = Reader.ReadToEnd();
       if (fileContent.Contains("your search text"))
           return true;
       else
           return false;
}
```

Comment: In this example, you don't use `Sb`.

Comment: or even just `return fileContent.Contains("your search text")`

Comment: `return true; else return false;` one of my favourite patterns.

Comment: @CodeInChaos: I used else to make the workflow clearer for a beginner.

Answer (score 5):

How about an one-liner:

```
 bool textExists = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("C:\\myfile2.txt").Contains("Search text");
```

That should do the trick :)

Answer (score 2):

In the example you show - there is no point loading into a `StringBuilder` in the first place. You already return the entire string in the call to `StreamReader.ReadToEnd`, so you may as well just check if this contains your substring.

StringBuilder is very useful if you are *changing* and *mutating* the string - but in this use case, you are not.

How about this:

```
private bool FileContainsString(string file, string substring)
{
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("C://myfile2.txt"))
    {
        return reader.ReadToEnd().Contains(substring);
    }
}
```

If you definitely want the string builder, then something like this:

```
private bool FileContainsString(string file, string substring)
{
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("C://myfile2.txt"))
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder(reader.ReadToEnd());
        return sb.ToString().Contains(substring);
    }
}
```

but in this specific scenario the StringBuilder is not actually doing anything useful.

Comment: Actually yes, its true i dont need a string builder.. Thank u so much.. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can read the whole file into a string with `File.ReadAllText`. Note that this does load the whole file at once, and thus costs a lot of memory if the file is large:

```
string content = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\myfile2.txt");
Console.WriteLine(content.Contains("needle"));
```

---

If your `needle` doesn't span multiple lines you can go with:

```
IEnumerable<string> content = File.ReadLines(@"C:\myfile2.txt");
Console.WriteLine(content.Any(line => line.Contains("needle")));
```

This only needs to keep one line in memory at a time, and thus scaled to larger files.

Answer (score -1):

Assign that to a string and then check if it contains the substring.

```
dim str as string
str = sb.tostring()
if str.contains("string") then
 'code
else
 'code
end if
```

Comment: Wrong language - this is C#. In any case - you don't need the if..else. Just return the result of `contains`

Comment: sorry, I have just put it in vb. In case you want to do anything else on return of true of false, we need if..else.