# I want to replace string with Stringbuilder but it breaks my code

Tags: c#, .net

How would I replace the string variable with a StringBuilder and still verify that a new line was read?

```
while ((strLine = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
```

I tried this and it runs forever because the StringBuilder variable is never null.

```
while ((strBuilder.Append(tempReader.ReadLine())) != null)
```

Comment: I think this question answers your question perfectly:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9785650/using-a-string-builder-ive-read-a-file-how-do-i-find-if-the-given-string-is

Comment: Why do you have the assumtion `strBuilder.Append(...)` should ever return `null`? From the documentation: "Returns StringBuilder A reference to this instance after the append operation is completed." (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.stringbuilder.append?view=netcore-3.1). Change it to `while ((strLine = reader.ReadLine()) != null) strBuilder.Append(strLine);`

Comment: One option is to switch to `while(!reader.EndOfStream)` or the equivalent for whatever `reader` is.

Comment: @Gintas thanks that solved it, please add as answer and I'll mark it

Comment: The expression `strLine = reader.ReadLine()` has itself a value: the value assigned to strLine - which may be null. `strBuilder.Append(...)` also has a value: always strBuilder itself, not the appended value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read a file via "using" statement instead of using while.
This question illustrates your problem perfectly:
[Using a string builder, i've read a file.. How do i find if the given string is present in the file or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9785650/using-a-string-builder-ive-read-a-file-how-do-i-find-if-the-given-string-is)